# Глючит STL стэк

Tags: stl, c++

Создаю стэк в методе:

```
std::stack<Tree<T>*, deque<T> > s;
```

Вызываю метод:

```
s.push_back(this); //this указывает на Тree<T>*
```

Пишет:

> «class std::stack*, std::deque*,
>   std::allocator*> > >» has no member named «push_back»|

Почему?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Читайте внимательно [документацию](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/). У `std::stack` нет метода `push_back`, только `push`. И на будущее, советую придерживаться правила: если вам кажется, что компилятор или стандартная библиотека работают неправильно, то это только кажется.

**UPD**: никто вас не обманывал, по [ссылке](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/) сказано, что *underlying container*, в вашем случае `std::deque`, должен поддерживать операцию `push_back`.

Comment: та понял уже да, прочитал. просто спешишь и таких вещей не замечаешь. у меня теперь другая трабла.